# Appending circle to both ends of a line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to append circle to both sides/ends of line. I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it

```
   var lineData = [{"x": 0, "y": 0}, {"x": 50, "y": 0}];
   svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
  .data(["arrow"])
  .enter().append("svg:marker")
  .attr("id", String)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 10)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 10)
  .attr("markerHeight", 10)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M3,-4 L10,0 L3,4");
   var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function (d) {
  return d.x;
  })
  .y(function (d) {
  return d.y;
  })
  .interpolate("linear");

     var line = svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
    .attr("id", "myPath")
    .attr("class", "link_arrow")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .style('cursor', 'move')
    .call(drag);

    var randomI = Math.round(Math.random() * myPath.getTotalLength());
    var myPoint = myPath.getPointAtLength(randomI);
    console.log("x=" + myPoint.x + "  y=" + myPoint.y);
    d3.select("line").append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", myPoint.x)
    .attr("cy", myPoint.y)
    .attr("r", 4.5);
    d3.select("line").append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", myPoint.x + randomI)
    .attr("cy", myPoint.y)
    .attr("r", 4.5);
```

After appending circle to line I would like to drag and stretch the line holding the circle as in this example: http://rigrr.rapilabs.com/. Any way this is different question all together, but I am writing it here because I want the circles to be appended keeping this functionality in mind.

Comment: You need to change your username.

Comment: I need to wait 30days

Comment: Flag your question for "in need of moderator attention" and say that you would like to change your username due to it being "inappropriate"". I'm sure they'll understand. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251682/what-should-be-done-about-offensive-names/251684#251684

Comment: I'd stick a circle marker on the start and end of the line. That way it will always stay on the line even when the line moves.

Comment: @Robert Longson I already have a arrow marker and then the circles would appear on hover so that I can stretch the line by holding the circle and dragging it. Can I have both circle and arrow marker?

Comment: No, you'd have to have a second shape. You could have an invisible line with two markers on it I guess.